# Google Sheets - Change Cell Content Based On Another Cell's Content w/3 Conditions

Tags: google-sheets

The utmost thanks and appreciation in advance!...

In a Google Sheets I have the following formula applied to a cell (H2):

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"...","✓"},G2))),-F2,"paid")

...that works perfectly as expected, though I don't recall how I built it and I'm needing to add a 3rd condition. Even though it works, I'm having problems deciphering it in order to include another condition.

My very lay translation as is, as I understand it and only the pertinent details related to what I'm wanting to add:

- If G2 contains '...', display in H2: the content of F2 (as a negative #)
- If G2 contains "✓", display in H2: "paid"

Lay-ly, what I'm wanting to add is:

- If G2 contains "" (an empty cell), display in H2 "" (an empty cell)

Without an idea of what I'm doing, I try:

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"...","✓",""},G2))),-F2,"paid","")

...though this doesn't seem to work. Halp!

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Solution**

If it's not empty, do your formula else "".

For example::

`if( g2<>"" , IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"...","✓"},G2))),-F2,"paid") , "" )`

I use this everywhere in my spreadsheets.

Comment: niiice, this is much more elegant and what I was looking to do, thanks!

Comment: I'm a newbie with a 'bad' rep, lol. Apparently my rep's too low for it to apply.

Comment: Ah jeez they don't make it easy for people starting out.